# Websocket client in C++ using boost::Beast - throwing error at write operation

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-asio, shared-ptr, boost-beast

Below is a piece of code which I am trying hard to make it successful. I use the reference code available at git hub https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start/websocket_client.html.
The problem is when I call the connect method and do write operation in same function it works, however it wont work if I put that in different function.

I am new to boost and shared_pointer, please excuse if I am not making any sense.

```
    // Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
    class CWebSocket_Sync : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CWebSocket_Sync>
    {
        tcp::resolver resolver_;
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
        boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_;
        std::string host_;
        std::string text_;

    public:
        // Resolver and socket require an io_context
        explicit
            CWebSocket_Sync(boost::asio::io_context& ioc)
            : resolver_(ioc)
            , ws_(ioc)
        {
        }

        void 
            connect(
                char const* host,
                char const* port,
                char const* text)
        {
            // Save these for later
            host_ = host;
            text_ = text;

            // Look up the domain name
            auto const results = resolver_.resolve(host, port);

            // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
            auto ep = net::connect(ws_.next_layer(), results);

            // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
            // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
            // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
            host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

            // Perform the websocket handshake
            ws_.handshake(host_, "/");

            //ws_.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));
            //// This buffer will hold the incoming message
            //beast::flat_buffer buffer;

            //// Read a message into our buffer
            //ws_.read(buffer);


        }

        void ServerCommand(char const* text)
        {
            ws_.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));   // <-- this line throw memory error 

            // This buffer will hold the incoming message
            beast::flat_buffer buffer;

            // Read a message into our buffer
            ws_.read(buffer);


            // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
            std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
        }

        void CloseConnection()
        {
            // Close the WebSocket connection
            ws_.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
        }

    };
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto const host = "127.0.0.1";
    auto const port = "7011";
    auto const loginCmd = "login"
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc)->connect(host, port, loginCmd);

    std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc)->ServerCommand(loginCmd);

    std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc)->CloseConnection();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc)->connect(host, port);
std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc)->ServerCommand(loginCmd);
std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc)->CloseConnection();
```

Each line creates a new client (`make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>`) and runs a single step on it. What you probably wanted:

```
auto client = std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc);
client->connect(host, port);
client->ServerCommand(loginCmd);
client->CloseConnection();
```

Indeed this works:

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace net       = boost::asio;
namespace beast     = boost::beast;
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
using net::ip::tcp;

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class CWebSocket_Sync : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CWebSocket_Sync> {
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_;
    std::string host_;

public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit CWebSocket_Sync(boost::asio::io_context& ioc)
        : resolver_(ioc), ws_(ioc) { }

    void connect(char const* host, char const* port) {
        // Save these for later
        host_ = host;

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver_.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        auto ep = net::connect(ws_.next_layer(), results);

        // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.handshake(host_, "/");
    }

    void ServerCommand(char const* text) {
        ws_.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));   // <-- this line throw memory error 

        beast::flat_buffer buffer;
        ws_.read(buffer);

        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }

    void CloseConnection() {
        ws_.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto const host = "127.0.0.1";
    auto const port = "7011";
    auto const loginCmd = "login";
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    auto client = std::make_shared<CWebSocket_Sync>(ioc);
    client->connect(host, port);
    client->ServerCommand(loginCmd);
    client->CloseConnection();
}
```

### SIMPLIFY

However, since nothing uses the shared lifetime and you're not using asynchronous calls anywhere, why not simply:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a13988edd976824)**

```
class CWebSocket_Sync {
```

and later:

```
    CWebSocket_Sync client(ioc);
    client.connect(host, port);
    client.ServerCommand(loginCmd);
    client.CloseConnection();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really worked like a charm.  Can you please guide me how can I learn more about this C++ boost::asio programming. I tried different portal and video didn't find any contain which can explain in simple way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think the beast tutorials are some of the best around.

Comment: I like your example because it is so much simpler than the official docs, short and sweet. However, if the server sends back 2/3 messages one after another; your code will only read 1 (the first). How would one read all the messages back at once? Sorry for the newbie question, just getting acquainted with Boost.

Comment: What do you mean, 2/3 as in 0.666666... message? Or 2 or three? I don't think the first can happen. And in the other case, you would just read multiple messages, right? E.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5336ed12cbf15f43

Comment: @Mecanik forgot to @ mention you ^

Comment: @sehe Thank you, that seems like a solution. However I was expecting that boost can offer something better, like a thread/loop waiting for incoming messages? Maybe I got this all wrong, so apologies; let me give you an example. Say I connect to CDP, send a command, I receive back 3 separate responses in 3 separate objects. I need something like send command <-> get response, does that make sense? Been looking around a lot and testing different snippets, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Mecanik How is the code I showed you not sufficient? It already shows you how to receive n separate responses in n separate objects. Also, I doubt people know what you mean with CDP. Also, consider asking a new question if you're stuck making something specific work.

Comment: @sehe Yes thank you, your code will suffice I believe. What I mean with "CDP" is Chrome Devs Protocol.

Comment: @sehe Your example posted for me works great, thanks a lot.